# onselected not working on parent lwc component?

Tags: lightning-web-components

Hi I have created 2 lwc components
From child i am passing Id and calling in parent. Once selected in parent i am not able to get value in parent.

child.js

```
const oEvent = new CustomEvent('lookupupdate',
                                    {
                                        'detail': {selectedRecord: value.Id}
                                    }
                        );
        this.dispatchEvent(oEvent);
```

parent.js

```
   HandleLookup(event){
console.log('Child in Parent' + event.detail);
this.selectedSourceId = event.detail;
```

}

parent.html

```
<c-source-lookuplwc onselected={HandleLookup}></c-source-lookuplwc>
```

i am not getting console.log('Child in Parent' + event.detail); once selected record from child lwc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your event is `lookupupdate` but your `HandleLookup` function is being called from the `onselect` event.

Try updating `onselected={HandleLookup}` to `onlookupupdate={HandleLookup}`